# hotmailで迷惑メールフォルダに振り分けられます

Tags: postfix

自前のサーバーに Postfix をたててそこから @hotmail.com アカウントにメール送信すると、迷惑メールフォルダに振り分けられます。

対策として以下を行いました。
・自前のサーバーの逆引き
・SPF
・DKIM

メールヘッダーをみると spf=pass、dkim=pass となっているので認証OKと判断されたと思いますが、それでも迷惑メールフォルダに振り分けられます。

```
CMM-Authentication-Results: hotmail.com; spf=pass (sender IP is
 xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx) smtp.mailfrom=xxx@xxx.xxx.xxx; dkim=pass
 header.d=xxx.xxx.xxx; x-hmca=pass header.id=xxx@xxx.xxx.xxx
```

迷惑メールフォルダに振り分けられないようにしたいのです。
アドバイスをよろしくお願い致します。

Comment: 質問にクローズ票を投じます。オフトピックである理由: 本質的に Hotmail が迷惑メールフィルターをどう実装しているかに依存し、さらにユーザーごとに学習しているのではと考えていて、そうすると回答が確定しないと思います。

Answer (score 4):

### 『新しい IP からメールを送信していますか?』

**http://mail.live.com/mail/troubleshooting.aspx**
をご確認ください。
Microsoft のトラブルシューティングとして公開されている情報です。

> 以前にメールの送信に使用されたことがない IP アドレスについては、通常、システムに評価は作成されていません。その結果、新しい IP から送信されたメールで配信に関する問題が発生する可能性が高くなります。

---

> 送信に関するドメインの評価が良好である場合、新しい IP の評価はより短時間で向上する可能性があります。新しい IP は、迷惑メールの苦情の割合が最低限に維持されている限り、ボリュームと配布リストの正確さに応じて 2 ～ 3 週間以内に完全に評価が上昇します。

---

全く新しいIPアドレスのサーバーからのメールを一定期間の間「迷惑メール」として判断するというルールがあることがわかります。

> Microsoft の SmartScreen® テクノロジは、Outlook.com のほかに、Exchange Server、Microsoft Office Outlook、Windows Live メールなどの Microsoft 製品にスパム対策フィルタリング機能を提供します。

---

> Outlook.com システム関連の内容 (@msn.com、@Outlook.com、@hotmail.com、または
> @live.com の付くアドレス)

このトラブルシューティングページに関連する事由である場合、『新しい IP は、迷惑メールの苦情の割合が最低限に維持されている限り、ボリュームと配布リストの正確さに応じて 2 ～ 3 週間以内に完全に評価が上昇します。』とのことですので、誠実なコンテンツを配信し、ユーザーに「迷惑メール」報告されないような運用を行うことで通常運用に組み入れられる…と言えます。

※経験的にですがメールサーバーとDNSの【SPF】【DKIM】設定において問題が無い場合でも、本件トラブルシューティングの内容のとおり「迷惑メールフォルダ」に振り分けられます。

Comment: はい、新しいIPからメール送信しています。しばらく様子をみようと思います。ありがとうございました。